# Oracle Column Constraint on char(4) field to not accept insert of 3 char value

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, constraints

Our issue is that we have XLS that has for example '0112' in a "Text" field

Then someone transfers this sheet (not sure if copy/paste) into another spreadsheet and they lose the 0, and the CSV has '112 ' (hard to see but there is a space after the 112)

Then some java code reads the csv and inserts the values into database table (Oracle 11g) and the field is type char(4) and so it seems to append a space to the end and we end up with '112 '.

Is there some way to add some constraint to the Oracle table/column to not automatically pad or add the extra space, we would prefer that we receive some error trying to insert 112 into a char(4)

Comment: check constraint char_length(col) = 4? (char_length or similar.)

Comment: Maybe a trigger, although it could be that `:new.YourColumn` is padded already in the trigger.

Comment: The specification of the `CHAR` data type is that it is always space-padded to the specified length.  There is basically no reason to ever prefer a `CHAR(x)` to a `VARCHAR2(x)` and plenty of reasons to prefer the `VARCHAR2`.  The fact that you can put a constraint on a `VARCHAR2` that checks the length is one of those.  Is changing the column to `VARCHAR2` an option?

Comment: @JustinCave as an option to change the field type it is quite unlikely, as our company is quite layered with bureaucracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try adding a constraint that checks the length of your string is 4, after having stripped off any spaces:

```
create table test1 (col1 char(4));

alter table test1 add constraint t1_chk check (length(trim(col1)) = 4);

-- the following inserts ok
insert into test1 values ('1234');

-- the following fails
insert into test1 values ('112 ');

commit;
```

Comment: I like that, let me fly that by our team and see what thoughts they have

Comment: I don't necessarily think that this is the best thing to do, it's just a possibility. What would be better is for your file process to be cleaned up (so many steps to transfer a file to the database; is it really necessary?). And CHAR? {shudders} Make that VARCHAR2, as has already been mentioned in earlier comments on your question.

Comment: Seems SQLFiddle has some bug... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7acb9/1  I tested this there and if I put that all in the build schema it works as you expect, but if I put the create & alter in the schema and the inserts into the Run SQL area it throws an error ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement...   I tested the same on our Oracle 11g R2 and it works fine

Comment: I think it's more that you need to put the inserts onto the left hand side and build the schema. I don't think the right hand panel accepts insert statements.